# react-native link not linking my package in react-native project in android

Tags: react-native

I have made a custom wrapper in android for react-native. When I am using react-native link to install dependancy in android for my Project, it is not doing any changes neither showing any errors. I have followed this document https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/how-to-build-a-react-native-android-bridge for same but I have to make changes in android files manually for my Module and package. Do I need to add build.gradle too in android directory? or any other file if I have missed. This is my file structure for bridge.

[image]

This is how I am importing my local package in another React Native package's package.json

[image]

Comment: could you try 
> react-native eject android

Comment: in Example project?

Comment: yes and first you remove an old android folder

Comment: Hi, I did it. But I think react-native link is not recognizing to link my local dependancy in project i.e. react-native-android-sharereceiver